# How are "Tele Photography" and "Candid Photography" different for a wedding?

Tags: portrait, terminology, telephoto, wedding

For wedding functions, are "tele photography" and "candid photography" the same?
If not, what are all the similarities and dissimilarities?

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Where did you hear these terms in a way that made you think that they might by synonyms?

Comment: I'm going on the assumption that you are hiring a wedding photographer, and saw these terms in a brochure, website, or even contract. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges here.

[Candid photography, as defined in this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candid_photography)

> A candid photograph is a photograph captured through motion mostly, **without creating a posed appearance**.

[A telephoto lens, as defined in this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephoto_lens)

> a telephoto lens is a specific type of a **long-focus lens** in which the physical length of the lens is shorter than the focal length.

The subjects of the photo (in your case, a wedding) is yet another totally unrelated variable in the equation.

You can combine any of the three (or their opposites) in every possible way.

1. staged photos of a wedding with wide angle lens
2. candid photo of a landscape (not a wedding) with a tele photo lens
3. etc

There are 8 possible combinations, each one yielding infinite possibilities for photos.